# Android Studio rendering problems: Preferences

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, rendering

Here is the code of my preferences.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key = "test"
        android:title = "Test"
        android:summary = "Yes It WORKED"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

android studios renderer gives me the following error message:

```
The following classes could not be found:
    -CheckBoxPreference(Fix build path)
    -PreferenceScreen(Fix build path)
```

Also it gave me errors when I didn't put in:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">
```

although Google itself (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) doesn't say a word about this. (Also they show an action bar when running the code all I get is a checkbox preference on the very top of the screen)

Answer (score 3):

**Create a xml folder inside res and move your .xml file (Ex:preferences.xml)inside it.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The interface of a `PreferenceFragment` must not be defined as a layout resource file, but as an XML resource file. This is explained in the link you gave but somehow hidden: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment

If you follow this approach, Android Studio's rendering works fine.